# I am not able to check application new release version on iOS App Store

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to check latest version on released application of iOS but code is not working. I am getting result count 0. Here is code, Please review it and tell me where is mistake?

```
NSDictionary* infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSString* appID = infoDictionary[@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=%@", appID]];
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSDictionary* lookup = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

if ([lookup[@"resultCount"] integerValue] == 1){
    NSString* appStoreVersion = lookup[@"results"][0][@"version"];
    NSString* currentVersion = infoDictionary[@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
    if (![appStoreVersion isEqualToString:currentVersion]){
        NSLog(@"Need to update [%@ != %@]", appStoreVersion, currentVersion);
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: your app is live or not?

Comment: Your current version matches with the version on app store?

Comment: hii @JigarDarji, my app is already live. and i am testing with degrading build number

Comment: hii, @Bmacin, yes it is matching, but i am not getting store app version with this code

Comment: If the app is not available or not for sale in that country, it will give the empty result. Try adding the country with the lookup url. i.e. http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.facebook.Facebook&country=us

Comment: @Bmacin, hii
my app is already available for sale on app store